# Detecting Gameobjects under Linerenderer

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have made a `LineRenderer` and I added an `EdgeCollider2D` to it.

Now I am trying to detect all `GameObjects` below my `LineRenderer`.
The objects below have Colliders as well.

- `LineRenderer` starts with first mouse position and ends with last mouse position
- `LineRenderer` has an `EdgeCollider2D`
- I need to get value from all objects which are under `LineRenderer`
- Project is in 2D

What I tried:

- Use Raycast,but using raycast I am getting values from object around too.

  And i want only to get values of Gameobjects under Linerenderer not values from All gameobjects touched by mouse
- Or if it is Possible to get gameobjects between 2 positions
  *So basicaly i need to get values from 10 of 100 objects,which are all together.F.E i have 100 mushrooms placed together,and every mushroom have its int value which is different.
  So moving my mouse around i need to select only this 10 mushrooms and take its value.

Here is my code so far

```
RaycastHit2D[] rays = Physics2D.RaycastAll(mousePos, lr.transform.forward);
Debug.DrawRay(new Vector3(startMousePosition.x, startMousePosition.y, 0), Vector3.up, Color.red, 5);
for (int i = 0; i < rays.Length; i++)
{
    RaycastHit2D ray = rays[i];

    if (isTOuched)
    {
        if (ray.collider.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            if (objektiOdRaycast.Contains(ray.collider.gameObject) == false)
            {
                objektiOdRaycast.Add(ray.collider.gameObject);
                for (int t = 0; t < objektiOdRaycast.Count; t++)
                {
                    tekst = objektiOdRaycast[t].GetComponent < GridSquare().tekst;
                }

                words.tekstSlova.text += tekst;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with a `Raycast` is: It only checks one single ray direction. That makes no sense in your use case.

You probably want to use [`Physics2D.OverlapCollider`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.OverlapCollider.html)

> Gets a list of all Colliders that overlap the given Collider.

and do e.g.

```
// Reference via the Inspector
public LineRenderer theLine;
// configure via the Inspector
public ContactFilter2D filter;

private Collider2D lineCollider;

private readonly List<Collider2D> overlaps = new List<Collider2D>();
private readonly HashSet<Collider2D> alreadySeen = new HashSet<Collider2D>();

private void Awake()
{
    // as fallback assume same GameObject
    if(!theLine) theLine = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();

    lineCollider = theLine.GetComponent<Collider2D>();
}

public void GetOverlappingObjects()
{
    var amount = Physics2D.OverlapCollider(lineCollider, filter, overlaps);

    for(var i = 0; i < amount; i++)
    {
        var overlap = overlaps[i];

        if(alreadySeen.Contains(overlap)) continue;

        alreadySeen.Add(overlap);

        var overlapObject = overlap.gameObject;

        // These checks are actually kind of redundant
        // the second heck for the component should already be enough
        // instead of the tag you could rather use a Layer and configure the filter accordingly
        if (!overlapObject.CompareTag("Player")) continue;
        if (!overlapObject.TryGetComponent<GridSquare>(out var gridSquare)) continue;
        
        words.tekstSlova.text += gridSquare.tekst; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but I already solved it with LinecastAll.Thansk for your effort

Comment: @samke Oh I thought there would be more positions on the line ^^ if it is only 2 positions anyway then a linecast is of course way more efficient ;) You should then probably also remove that edge collider